# Unable to Launch any Browser Drivers using Selenium, testng

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a testing framework for a project using Java selenium and Testng
I am using below maven dependencies -

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And i am trying to launch the drivers as below -

```
 case CHROME: System.out.println("*****Launching Chrome Driver****");
                             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/path/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");
                     
                             driver = new ChromeDriver();
                             driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

                case FIREFOX: System.out.println("***LAUNCHING FIREFOX BROWSER****");
                              System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/path/Desktop/geckodriver");
                              driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                              driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

I tried by giving both `.exe` and without `.exe`

Yet the drivers are ot getting launched and i am getting below error -

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running sampleTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@4f4a7090
***LAUNCHING FIREFOX BROWSER****

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.336 sec <<< FAILURE!
sampletest(sampleTest)  Time elapsed: 0.061 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:146)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.usingFirefoxBinary(GeckoDriverService.java:160)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
```

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/path/Desktop/geckodriver");

Here geckodriver.exe     ".exe" is missing in your code